# Двумерные списки Python

Tags: python, list

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Возможно ли создать двумерный список, если не известна длина вложенного списка? 
list2 = [[1, 2] , [1], [], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ...]
Пример кода:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
list2 = []
for el in list1:
    for x1 in len(list1):
        list2.append([])
    for x2 in ???
        *математические действия*
        list2[x1].append(num)
```

Comment: Во-первых строчка `for x1 in len(list1):` не будет работать. Используйте `for x1 in range(len(list1)):`. А во-вторых строка со знаками вопроса: `for x2 in el:` (что логично. `el` - внутренние списки, значит, по ним и нужно идти)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list2 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list2.append([])
    for j in range(0,(i**2)%10):
        list2[i].append(j)
print(list2)
```

вот такой пример подойдет?